# matplotlib doesn't show real time in x axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

[image]

I feed the following animation from data collected from a remote device via Paramiko.
If I understood the concept of animation interval, with a value of 1000 sec, the animation should update the plot each 1000 ms and x axis is supposed to show real time units in seconds.

After measuring the animation function and different sections inside, it looks like the animation function takes more than 1s to execute and the section of the animation that pulling inf. from the remote devices takes most of the time.

It doesn't matter if the pulling function takes more than one second, the most important is that the information drawn corresponds to the second units in the x axis.

How to make sure that the plot will show real time units (seconds in my case) in X axis and corrsponding y values in Y axis even if the reading procedure takes more than the time units?

```
def GetInfo(stdout):
    ...

def init():
    line.set_data(\[\], \[\])
    return line,


def animate(i):
    ### I
    tRefAnim = time.time()
    global penQ
    global halfTimer
    global tRef

    ### II
    tRefSess = time.time()
    Session = CParam(IP,login , hostname, sshpass)
    Session.SendCmd(command)
    DAMINFO = GetInfo(Session.stdout)
    print "Device Session time = " + "{0:.3f}".format(time.time()-tRefSess)

    ### III    
    tRefAnn = time.time()
    ...    
    print "Conditional annotations = " + "{0:.3f}".format(time.time()-tRefAnn)

    ### IV
    tRefDraw = time.time()

    # Collect data into x and y lists
    xdata.append(i)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()


    ###changing the xmax dynamically
    if i >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax+(xmax/2))
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()

    ###changing the ymax dynamically
    if y >= ymax:
        ax.set_ylim(ymin, y+(y/10))
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()

    #line.set_data(x, y)
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    print "Drawing time = " + "{0:.3f}".format(time.time()-tRefDraw)
    print "animate time = " + "{0:.3f}".format(time.time()-tRefAnim)
    return line,




# initializing parameters
...

#initial max x axis
init_xlim = 5
init_ylim = 3500

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, init_xlim), ylim=(0, init_ylim))
ax.grid()
line, = ax.plot(\[\], \[\], lw=2)
#x = np.linspace(4, 5, 1000)
xdata, ydata = \[\], \[\]


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=2000, interval=1000, blit=False)
plt.show()][1]
```

The result of time measuring

```
Drawing time = 0.000
animate time = 1.149
Device Session time = 1.167
Conditional annotations = 0.000
Drawing time = 0.000
animate time = 1.168
Device Session time = 1.059
Conditional annotations = 0.000
Drawing time = 0.000
animate time = 1.060
Device Session time = 1.072
Conditional annotations = 0.000
Drawing time = 0.000
animate time = 1.073
Device Session time = 1.049
Conditional annotations = 0.000
Drawing time = 0.069
animate time = 1.119
Device Session time = 1.155
Conditional annotations = 0.000
Drawing time = 0.000
animate time = 1.156
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the plot showing time with a precision of +/- 300 ms.

- I set the animation.FuncAnimation **interval** parameter to 1500 ms
  slightly bigger than the time the animate function takes (~1200 ms).
- I used global variable for time reference.

But, obviously it is a workaround.
I am open to any other suggestions.